# Update a column after select where does not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How can i update a column after i have selected records which do not exist from another table.
Need to update Status column to 0 when there are certain records which do not exist.

```
SELECT *
FROM [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].[Test1] p1
WHERE p1.[Age] is  not null and
      Not EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].[Test2]  p2   WHERE ( p1.[Surname] =p2.[Surname]) )
```

Comment: Are you using MsSql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically translates to an `update`:

```
UPDATE [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].Test1
    SET status = 0
    WHERE Age is  not null and
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].[Test2] p2
                      WHERE p2.[Surname] = Test1.[Surname]
                     );
```

The only subtlety is that SQL Server doesn't allow you to declare an alias in the `UPDATE` clause.  You could use a `FROM` clause but that hardly seems necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer LEFT JOIN:

```
UPDATE p1
SET STATUS = 0
FROM [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].[Test1] p1 LEFT JOIN
   [BankingServicesReconciliations].[dbo].[Test2] p2 ON p1.[Surname] = p2.[Surname] and p2.[Age] IS NOT NULL
WHERE p1.[Age] IS NOT NULL
  AND p2.[Surname] IS NULL
```

This one is way much cleaner and understandable than EXISTS approach and, you better believe me, is WAY MUCH FASTER!